# Django testing named URLs with additional GET parameters

Tags: django, testing, reverse

I am trying to write some tests for a Django application I'm working on but I haven't yet decided on the exact urls I want to use for each view.  Therefore, I'm using named urls in the tests.

For example, I have a url named dashboard:

```
c = Client()
resp = c.get(reverse('dashboard'))
```

This view should only be available to logged in users.  If the current user is anonymous, it should redirect them to the login page, which is also a named url.  However, when it does this, it uses an additional GET parameter to keep track of the url it just came from, which results in the following:

```
/login?next=dashboard
```

When I then try to test this redirect, it fails because of these additional parameters:

```
# It's expecting '/login' but gets '/login?next=dashboard'
self.assertRedirects(resp, reverse('login'))
```

Obviously, it works if I hard code them into the test:

```
self.assertRedirects(resp, '/login?next=dashboard')
```

But then, if I ever decide to change the URL for my dashboard view, I'd have to update every test that uses it.

Is there something I can do to make it easier to handle these extra parameters?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see, `reverse(...)` returns a string. You can use it as:

```
self.assertRedirects(resp, '%s?next=dashboard' % reverse('login'))
```

Comment: Almost had it, but you missed the entire point of the OP's question. He's not worried about the "login" portion of the URL, but the `next` GET param. The URL "dashboard" may change in the future, so the OP doesn't want to hardcode it in the tests. @Dan: you can basically follow the same approach here, but substitute "dashboard" with "%s" and pass `reverse('dashboard')` for the string param.

Comment: The problem is that GET parametrs can't be written in urls.py directly, so @Dan you can use LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboard/' in settings.py to redirect needed url after login. And if you use login_required decorator for views function, anonymous will be redirect to this url.

Comment: You don't need to do anything in urls.py. The `next` param literally means "go to the following URL afterwards". He just needs to assert that the URL includes '?next=%s' % reverse('dashboard')`. Then, no matter what URL "dashboard" resolves to, it will match.